# How to detect Google oauth window closed action from user

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin

In my web based application I am using Google and Facebook OAuth Log-in.

How do I capture the event when user closes the Google login window?

I want to hide my gif loader when user closes the Google login window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var gmailWindow = window.open('YOUR_GMAIL_URL','Gmail', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes');
var timer = setInterval(
 function(){
   if(gmailWindow.closed){
     clearInterval(timer);
     alert('window closed')
   }
},10)
```

Try this.